# scanning ip address using webclient

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1, webclient

I have a problem. I want to receive a string using an IP address as a Uri. I don't know the IP address, so I am scanning a range of IP addresses from 0 to 20 (see code below). When a string is received from a  specific IP, I use that IP address to connect to that server.

```
string IP = "10.0.0."
int i = 0;
isIPFound = false;

GetStatus() {
    string uri = "http://"  + IP + i.ToString() + "somepath";
    client.DownloadStringCompleted +=  
        new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_downloadStringCompleted);
    client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(uri));           
}

client_downloadStringCompleted(s,e)
{
   if (e.Error == null) {
       isIPfound = true;
   } else {
       if (i < 20) {
           i++;
           GetStatus(i);
       }
   }
}
```

The code locates the IP address correctly but it's taking time to receive the string. how can I improve efficiency so that when it locates the string in IP `10.0.0.n`, it subsequently connects to IP `10.0.0.n + 1`? (Ex: if it received string from 10.4.8.12 but IP is being 10.4.8.13)

Can anyone tell me whether I am using the correct procedure? If not, what would be the best method?

Thanks

Comment: are you randomly hitting unknown sources?

Comment: @codeIgnoto.. yeah.. I want to connect to a system in local network.. I want to get the ip address of the system which phone to receive string. Programmatically trying to get the Ip address

Comment: you could use Task Parallel library to improve the experience

Comment: Ok.. Am i using the right method? 
Thanks for replay ...

Comment: you are doin good with DownloadStringAsync,that is an improvement